# Pusher filling up with Laravel Broadcasts

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, websocket, pusher

Recently been observing this in our Laravel project that Pusher is getting clogged up with messages upto the limit. This is abnormal for usage of peak concurrent - 16 and 4 million messages a day.

Going through the Pusher dashboard, below is the extent of the damage being done.

[image]

There is a specific pattern of usage. When I turn off the supervisord worker, the graph stops and when I start the worker again, it comes back up in a predictable pattern shown in the graph below.

[image]

Below is a sample message I got when running `redis-cli monitor`.

[image]

As you can see above, the index [attempts] is **69507**. Does that mean that this event has been broadasted 69507 times ? Why would an event be broadcasted so many times ? When does an event stop being broadcasted ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Here is the code for the `AgendaParticipantUpdated` event. Would be great if there is something fundamentally wrong in the way the event has been implemented.

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\AgendaParticipant;
use App\Agenda;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class AgendaParticipantUpdated implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /** @var agendaParticipant */
    public $agendaParticipant;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param AgendaParticipant $agendaParticipant
     */
    public function __construct(AgendaParticipant $agendaParticipant)
    {
        $this->agendaParticipant = $agendaParticipant;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel("meetings.{$this->agendaParticipant->agenda->meeting->id}");
    }

    /**
     * Get the data to broadcast.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        $agenda = Agenda::where('id', $this->agendaParticipant->agenda->id)->first();
        $agenda->load(['participants' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('order')->orderBy('id');
        }, 'participants.member.user']);

        return [
            'agendaParticipant' => $this->agendaParticipant,
            'agenda' => $agenda,
        ];
    }
}
```

There are lots of other broadcasts too like this one :

[image]

As you see above, this broadcast has attempt count of 873245.

Below is the code for the `DiscussionCreated` event :

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Discussion;
use App\Member;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;


class DiscussionCreated implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * @var Discussion
     */
    public $discussion;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param Discussion $discussion
     */
    public function __construct(Discussion $discussion)
    {
        $this->discussion = $discussion;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        $author = Member::where('id',$this->discussion->author_id)->firstOrFail();
        return new PrivateChannel("group.{$author->group_id}");
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        if(\Auth::check())
        {
            $group = $this->discussion->author->group;

            $group->load(['meetings', 'facilitator']);
            $facilitatorId = optional($group->facilitator)->id;
            $members = $group->members()->with('user')->get();
            $discussion = $this->discussion;
            $member = auth()->user()->activeGroupMember;

            $list_read_discussions=\DB::table('members')
                ->where('member_id', '=', $member->id)
                ->join('acknowledgements', 'members.id', '=', 'acknowledgements.member_id')
                ->join('discussions', 'discussions.id', '=', 'acknowledgements.discussion_id')
                ->where('discussions.target_type','=','App\Group')
                ->whereNotExists( function($q) {
                    $q->select(\DB::raw(1))
                        ->from('replies')
                        ->where('acknowledgements.discussion_id','=','replies.discussion_id')
                        ->whereColumn('replies.updated_at', '>','acknowledgements.updated_at');
                })
                ->distinct('acknowledgements.discussion_id')
                ->pluck('acknowledgements.discussion_id');

            $group_discussions_count= $discussion->count();
            $group_read_discussions=$list_read_discussions;
            $unreadGroupCount=max(0,$group_discussions_count - $group_read_discussions->count());

            $authedMemberId = auth()->id();

            //private menu section
            $authedMember = auth()->user()->activeGroupMember;
            foreach($members as $target){
                $discussions_to_target_count=\App\Discussion::
                where('target_type','=','App\Member')
                    ->where('target_id','=',$target->id)
                    ->Where('author_id','=',$authedMember->id)
                    ->count();

                $discussions_from_target_count=\App\Discussion::
                where('target_type','=','App\Member')
                    ->where('target_id','=',$authedMember->id)
                    ->Where('author_id','=',$target->id)
                    ->count();

                $read_discussions_to_target_count=\DB::table('acknowledgements')
                    ->where('acknowledgements.member_id', '=', $authedMember->id)
                    ->join('discussions', 'discussions.id', '=', 'acknowledgements.discussion_id')
                    ->where('discussions.target_type','=','App\Member')
                    ->where('discussions.target_id', '=', $target->id)
                    ->where('discussions.author_id', '=', $authedMember->id)
                    ->whereNotExists( function($q) {
                        $q->select(\DB::raw(1))
                            ->from('replies')
                            ->where('acknowledgements.discussion_id','=','replies.discussion_id')
                            ->whereColumn('replies.updated_at', '>','acknowledgements.updated_at');
                    })

                    ->distinct('acknowledgements.discussion_id')
                    ->pluck('acknowledgements.discussion_id')
                    ->count();

                $read_discussions_from_target_count=\DB::table('acknowledgements')
                    ->where('acknowledgements.member_id', '=', $authedMember->id)
                    ->join('discussions', 'discussions.id', '=', 'acknowledgements.discussion_id')
                    ->where('discussions.target_type','=','App\Member')
                    ->where('discussions.target_id', '=', $authedMember->id)
                    ->where('discussions.author_id', '=', $target->id)
                    ->whereNotExists( function($q) {
                        $q->select(\DB::raw(1))
                            ->from('replies')
                            ->where('acknowledgements.discussion_id','=','replies.discussion_id')
                            ->whereColumn('replies.updated_at', '>','acknowledgements.updated_at');
                    })

                    ->distinct('acknowledgements.discussion_id')
                    ->pluck('acknowledgements.discussion_id')
                    ->count();


                $target->unreadPrivateCount=max(0,$discussions_to_target_count
                    +$discussions_from_target_count
                    -$read_discussions_from_target_count
                    -$read_discussions_to_target_count);
            }

            $this->discussion->replies = [];
            $this->discussion->replies_count = 0;
            $this->discussion->sort = $this->discussion->created_at->toDateTimeString();
            $this->discussion->has_user_subscribed = 1;

            return [
                'discussion' => $this->discussion ? $this->discussion->toArray() : array(),
            ];

        }    
    }
}
```

Would appreciate any help on this since it is interfering with our daily operations.

Answer (score 1):

> As you can see above, the index [attempts] is 69507. Does that mean that this event has been broadasted 69507 times?

Yes. It means that your queue worker has processed this job (broadcast) almost 70K times.

> Why would an event be broadcasted so many times?

I believe the reason is that your broadcast job throws an Exception (it is failing). Laravel would keep trying to execute the failed jobs until they either: execute successfully without any exceptions or until max attempts/timeout values are reached. From the attached screenshots, I believe that you haven't configured such values. (`maxTries` is empty in your screenshots)

> When does an event stop being broadcasted ? Am I doing something wrong ?

I think you need to do two things:

1. Define the maximum number of attempts for your queue workers. One of the ways to do so is by specifying `tries` parameter for your queue workers, i.e. run `php artisan queue:work --tries=3`(Check [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#max-job-attempts-and-timeout) for more information).
2. Check your error log files and find the exception being thrown from your broadcast jobs and fix it.

I hope this helps. Please let me know if you have any follow-up questions.

*Update:* Consider giving [Laravel Horizon](https://horizon.laravel.com/) a try. It would give you a nice dashboard to monitor your jobs (including broadcasts), see the number of failing jobs and the causes (exceptions). It also has built-in notification settings that could help you figure out early when there is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that can be you case but I encountered a similar problem using Laravel 5.6

Whet I found out was that the cron for the queued jobs with

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I forgot to specify the user processing the cron, so the process was handled by the super user and subsequently locking up files / resources with the wrong permissions

so, I changed the cron command to

```
* * * * * apache:apache cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

which fixed my problem. Now I have my logs clear with no failed process attempts